# Is this bathroom wiring correct?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am in the United States. The vanity switch has power at the switch. The light/fan has power at the light.

[image: schematic]

Comment: The diagram doesn't reflect your claim that power comes into the fan, it appears to come into the GFCI receptacle which is near the switch.  Any way you could add a diagram showing the cabling topology where the components physically are and which cables connect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This isn't *wrong* as old work, but it's decidedly suboptimal

While the wiring depicted is Code-correct for an existing (pre-2011) installation insofar as it goes (can't tell about grounds since they aren't depicted), it does have one functionality flaw: namely, that a GFCI trip for any reason will kill all the lights.  Unfortunately, that's not fixable here without rewiring the whole setup, which'd require a bunch of /2/2 cable and a section of ½" ENT with THHNs in it for the fan switch run (due to having to stub end both neutrals at the switch box).

If this is new work, though, this fails to provide a neutral at the fan switch, which is a NEC 404.2(C) violation.  Fixing it at a minimum would require /3 cable, but the ENT approach is preferred as it would provide for separate neutrals for the light and fan smart switches.